# Pandas: Exception while plotting two data frames on the same graph

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have two Pandas DataFrame that I am trying to plot on the same graph.

- all_data: need to plot this as a line graph
- points_of_interest: need to plot this as a scatter plot in the same graph

Here is the code that I use to plot them:

```
axes = all_data[ASK_PRICE].plot(figsize=(16, 12))
points_of_interest[ASK_PRICE].plot(figsize=(16, 12), ax = axes, kind='scatter')
pylab.show()
```

When I run this code it says:

```
>>> points_of_interest[ASK_PRICE].plot(figsize=(16, 12), ax = axes, kind='scatter')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/shubham/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 3599, in __call__
**kwds)
  File "/home/shubham/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 2673, in plot_series
**kwds)
  File "/home/shubham/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 2430, in _plot
% kind)
ValueError: plot kind 'scatter' can only be used for data frames
```

I have confirmed that both the dataframes are of type 'DataFrame'. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to use the `pd.Series` `points_of_interest[ASK_PRICE]` with `plot(kind='scatter')`.  You assumed it would naturally take the index vs the values.  That is unfortunately not true.

Try this

```
axes = all_data[ASK_PRICE].plot(figsize=(16, 12))
poi = points_of_interest[ASK_PRICE]
poi.reset_index().plot.scatter(0, 1, ax=axes)
pylab.show()
```